# Uncaught Reference Error Value not defined

Tags: javascript, html

I could not find out what is the problem with this line of code. I was trying to block the user from entering keycode 32 which is space.

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkqG1.png)

Line of code:
`: <input type="password" id="customer_password_input" onkeyup="new_password_guide()" onkeydown="javascript: var keycode = keyPressed(event); if(keycode==32){ return false; }" onblur="edit_password_validation()" autocomplete="new-password" disabled>`

Comment: It says it hasn't been defined, there's nothing in your code which would define it, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Why though? Sounds like your code has problems if you're restricting characters in passwords. IMO authentication code is not a place for novices. Clever people know more about SQL injections than you do!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the `keyPressed` function.

```
<script>
function keyPressed(event) {
  // work with it here
}
</script>
```

Comment: thanks it worked with '$("#customer_password_input").keydown(function(event) {  
 
   if (event.keyCode == '32') {  
       return false;
      }  
 });'